# Trouble using remove_filter to override function in parent theme

Tags: filters, child-theme

I'm having trouble using `remove_filter` to override the read more links in my parent theme.

Here's the parent theme functions:

```
/* Modify the '[...]' Read More Text */
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'hoot_modify_read_more_link' );
if ( apply_filters( 'hoot_force_excerpt_readmore', true ) ) {
    add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'hoot_insert_excerpt_readmore_quicktag', 11 );
    add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'hoot_replace_excerpt_readmore_quicktag', 11, 2 );
} else {
    add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'hoot_modify_read_more_link' );
}

/**
 * Modify the '[...]' Read More Text
 *
 * @since 1.0
 * @access public
 * @return string
 */
function hoot_modify_read_more_link( $more = '[&hellip;]' ) {
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $more;

    $read_more = esc_html( hoot_get_mod('read_more') );
    $read_more = ( empty( $read_more ) ) ? sprintf( __( 'Read More %s', 'brigsby' ), '&rarr;' ) : $read_more;
    global $post;
    $read_more = '<a class="more-link" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) . '">' . $read_more . '</a>';
    return apply_filters( 'hoot_readmore', $read_more ) ;

}
```

And here's my functions in my child theme's function.php:

```
function dw_remove_parent_read_more() {
    remove_filter('excerpt_more', 'hoot_modify_read_more_link');
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'dw_remove_parent_read_more',999);

function dw_modify_read_more_link($more = '[&hellip;]') {

    if ( is_admin() )
        return $more;

    $read_more = esc_html( hoot_get_mod('read_more') );
    $read_more = ( empty( $read_more ) ) ? sprintf( __( 'Read More %s', 'brigsby' ), '' ) : $read_more;
    global $post;
    $read_more = '<div><a class="more-link" href="' . esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) . '">' . $read_more . '</a></div>';
    return apply_filters( 'hoot_readmore', $read_more ) ; 
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'dw_modify_read_more_link', 999);
```

The current result is that two read more links are now showing, both the parent theme's and my child theme's. What am I doing wrong :) ?

Answer (score 2):

**A Note on Priorities**

Note that if you're trying to remove a function using `remove_action()` or `remove_filter()` and the function has had a priority assigned to it, you must include the priority when removing it, or it won't work.

**So if the function in the parent theme looks like this:**

```
<?php
function parent_function() {
    // Contents for your function here.
}
add_action( 'init', 'parent_function', 15 );
?>
<?php
function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'parent_function', 15 );
}
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'child_remove_parent_function' );
?>
.
```

you'll need to include the same priority value when removing it:

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the 'Read More' link being displayed was from the `wp_trim_excerpt` hook rather than `excerpt_more` hook. Just needed to switch my `add_filter` and `remove_filter` to reference the appropriate hooks.

```
function dw_remove_parent_read_more() {
    remove_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'hoot_replace_excerpt_readmore_quicktag', 11, 2);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'dw_remove_parent_read_more',11);

function dw_replace_excerpt_readmore_quicktag( $text, $raw_excerpt ) {
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $text;
    $read_more = dw_modify_read_more_link();
    $text = str_replace( '<!--hoot-read-more-quicktag-->', '', $text );
    return $text . $read_more ;
}

add_filter('wp_trim_excerpt', 'dw_replace_excerpt_readmore_quicktag', 11,2);
```